# How can I create grid view of images? On click of a image it should open that image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, grid, uiimage

How can I create the grid of images, like How it happens in the **iPad photos app** and on image **click** it should open that image, Can anybody give me some tutorial link or example code? Thanx in advance.

Comment: I used DTGridView and it is fine but i don't know how to specify indexpath for images. I have an array of 25 images.I have 5 rows and 5 columns. What i want is that i want to display first 5 images in 5 column and 6t image on 2nd row and so on... If i pass **[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arr_images objectAtIndex:columnIndex]]]** this in **-(DTGridViewCell *)gridView:(DTGridView *)gv viewForRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex column:(NSInteger)columnIndex** then images are set in column only. I want the next image to be set in next row after 5th column. Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several open source options to consider:

https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController
https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone
https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView/
https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView
https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit  (SSCollectionView)

Some of these will enlarge the photo automatically, and for other's you'll have to implement that part yourself. I've personally used FGallery and found it very full-featured, easy to use, and stable.